# How do I clear this pseudo-checkbox using jQuery + Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, greasemonkey

I'm currently working on a website that requires a share button to vk.com (the Russian Facebook).

The problem is the share doesn't seem to work when an the "add image" checkbox is selected. I've tried `$("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);` using Greasemonkey, but it did not work.
I think it's because the checkbox is created using a function and not pure HTML.

The checkbox is created using the following function:

```
if (!window.imageCheck) {
   window.imageCheck = new Checkbox(ge('add_image'), {
     checked: true,
     label: 'add image',
     width: 150,
     onChange: function(val) {
       if (val) {
         showImage(currentImage);
         recountImages();
       } else {
         hide('image_cont', 'select_image');
       }
       doResize(true);
     }
   });
}
doResize(true);
```

When I view the page source, the checkbox is actually in an hidden input. `<input type="hidden" id="add_image" name="add_image" value="1" />` I've tried doing `$("#add_image").val("0");` hoping that it would work, but still nothing.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the title and the question... Greasemonkey? Share what how?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a click event to the appropriate node should do the trick.  Something like:

```
if ( $("#add_image").val()  !=  "0") {
    //--- Assumes #add_image is the user-interactive node (seems doubtful)
    var clickableNode   = $("#add_image");
    var clickEvent      = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    clickableNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

**However**, it is not certain that `#add_image` is the correct node.  Answer the following questions if it doesn't work:

1. Where is that `ge()` function coming from?  What library? Or post the source, if it's inline.
2. Does `<input id="add_image"...` have the onChange handler in **its** source?  What does Firebug's *Events* tab show?
3. Verify `#add_image`s value is `"1"` when the checkbox is checked and `"0"` otherwise.
4. Link to the target page or save its code to disk and link to it at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/).

Also, [a design flaw introduced into Greasemonkey 1.0](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1614), may be causing some problems (even if you don't use jQuery).  Try adding `// @grant GM_getValue` to the [Metadata Block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) of your script.